# Linking to bootstrap modal on another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site where everyone's bio pops up in a modal with the code setup on template-team.php like this

```
<div class="tem_pic" id ="<?php echo $p->ID ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leader-modal-<?php echo $p->ID; ?>"
```

Then I have a slider on the template-homepage.php that calls out certain people. I want those sliders to be able to go to the team page, then open up that corresponding person's bio

```
<a class="slide_logo white_right_arrow" data-target="#leader-modal-<?php echo $p->ID; ?> href="/team"></a>
```

I can't get the modal to popup when I get to the page though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with combination of PHP and JS. Let's say your `template-team.php` is assigned to `https://example.com/team`. Now, to pop up a team's bio modal, we create URLs like `https://example.com/team?m=Junaid` (m for member)

Using the following code we can popup a modal based on the URL parameters on page load.

```
<?php if ( isset($_GET['m']) ) : ?>
<?php // I'll skip how to open a specific modal, I think you're separating those with team member ID or whatever ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('window').on('load', function(){
            // to open a modal in JS
            jQuery('#target-modal-ID').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Put this code in `template-team.php` after JS load. Customize and modify the code to your requirements.